# Как настроить Sublime Text для быстрой работы с Flexbox?

Tags: sublime-text, flexbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить Sublime Text 2, чтобы он распознавал синаксис flexbox.

Comment: посетите эту страницу, возможно поможет. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

`Install Package`

`Flexbox Snippets`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Она у меня уже есть, но команды css, которые для flexbox не узнаются им и не выделяются цветами. На видеоуроках в ютубе у авторов ролика всё ок